# Python tkinter button widget executing function outside of parent Toplevel widget class

Tags: python, function, tkinter, window, toplevel

Starting writing a tkinter program based on some youtube examples:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sys


def login():
    username = user_entry.get()
    pw = password_entry.get()
    if (user, pw) in Users:
        if (username, pw) == ('Admin', 'AdminPassword'):
            '''LOAD FIRST TIME ADMIN LOGON???????'''
            login_window.destroy()
        else:
            '''LOAD NORMAL USER or NORMAL ADMIN WINDOW'''
    else:
        warn.config(text="Invalid Username or Password", fg="black", bg='red')




class main_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title('Pilot Flight and Duty Tracker')
        self.geometry('1000x700+250+50')
        self.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        self._frame = None
        Login_Window = Login(self)

        Users = [('Admin','AdminPassword')]

    def switch_frame(self, frame_name):
        new_frame = frame_name(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()




class Login(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title('User Login')
        self.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        self.attributes('-topmost', True)
        self.geometry('230x200+625+275')
        self.title('User Login')
        self.grab_set()
        self.transient(master)
        userlabel = tk.Label(self, text="Employee ID:", font='arial 10 bold')
        userlabel.place(x=25, y=5)
        user_entry = tk.Entry(self, relief='groove', width=25, font='arial 10', bd=1)
        user_entry.place(x=25, y=30)
        passwordlabel = tk.Label(self, text="Password:", font='arial 10 bold')
        passwordlabel.place(x=25, y=70)
        password_entry = tk.Entry(self, relief='groove', width=25, font='arial 10', show="*", bd=1)
        password_entry.place(x=25, y=95)
        warn = tk.Label(self, font='arial 10 bold')
        warn.place(x=25, y=135)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Login", relief='groove', width=12, font='arial 15 bold', justify='center', command=login)
        button.place(x=37, y=140)


run = main_window()
run.mainloop()
```

Worked fine until I needed the Toplevel widget's 'button' to call the 'login' function. I know there's probably something I can add to the function to fix all of this, but, it seems no matter where I place the function, or its indentation level, I always get an error on callback. If I place the function between **init** for the top level widget, and the rest of the buttons, labels and such, they don't initialize with the rest of the Toplevel widget. So, is there a way to get this function to work inside the Toplevel widget class I've defined?

Answer (score 1):

Add your variables as class variables in `__init__`, that way it will be accessible in other methods of class -

```
import os
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import sys


class main_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title('Pilot Flight and Duty Tracker')
        self.geometry('1000x700+250+50')
        self.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        self._frame = None
        Login_Window = Login(self)

        Users = [('Admin','AdminPassword')]

    def switch_frame(self, frame_name):
        new_frame = frame_name(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()




class Login(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title('User Login')
        self.resizable(width = False, height = False)
        self.attributes('-topmost', True)
        self.geometry('230x200+625+275')
        self.title('User Login')
        self.grab_set()
        self.transient(master)
        userlabel = tk.Label(self, text="Employee ID:", font='arial 10 bold')
        userlabel.place(x=25, y=5)
        self.user_entry = tk.Entry(self, relief='groove', width=25, font='arial 10', bd=1)
        self.user_entry.place(x=25, y=30)
        passwordlabel = tk.Label(self, text="Password:", font='arial 10 bold')
        passwordlabel.place(x=25, y=70)
        self.password_entry = tk.Entry(self, relief='groove', width=25, font='arial 10', show="*", bd=1)
        self.password_entry.place(x=25, y=95)
        self.warn = tk.Label(self, font='arial 10 bold')
        self.warn.place(x=25, y=135)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Login", relief='groove', width=12, font='arial 15 bold', justify='center', command=self.login)
        button.place(x=37, y=140)

    def login(self):
        self.username = self.user_entry.get()
        self.pw = self.password_entry.get()
        if (self.username, self.pw) in Users:
            if (self.username, self.pw) == ('Admin', 'AdminPassword'):
                '''LOAD FIRST TIME ADMIN LOGON???????'''
                self.destroy()
            else:
                '''LOAD NORMAL USER or NORMAL ADMIN WINDOW'''
        else:
            self.warn.config(text="Invalid Username or Password", fg="black", bg='red')


run = main_window()
run.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Hadn't realized I needed them to have self. in front... also didn't remember that I needed (self) for the login function.

Comment: A follow-up question- under the first if statement of the login function(I deleted the second one for now), I added 'self.warn.config(text='Login Successful!'), bg='green', justify='center'. I added a time delay so you could see the label change before it destroys. I am getting no errors, but it is not changing the look of the label widget, and I'm not sure why...

Comment: time.sleep() puts the thread to sleep before it renders the warning. Use 'after' for that. Replace self.destroy to 'self.after(2000, self.destroy)' to add a 2 second delay